# How to compute y caret

Tags: self-study, notation

I have been given a data points $x_i,y_i,1\leq i\leq n$. I was asked to compute the standard error of regression coefficients estimates. As in the formula, I have to compute
$\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2.$ But how one defines $\hat{y}_i$?

Comment: The caret notation, e.g. $\hat{y}$ usually means "estimated". Is this ordinary least squares regression? If so, it is easy to find the formula on the net Also, I presume that you were given more than one data point.  Finally, if this is homework it should have the homework tag.

Comment: @PeterFlom Yes. It is an ordinary least squares regression

Answer (score 2):

In ordinary least squares regression the formula for $\hat{y_i}$ is

$\hat{y}_i= \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1X_1 + ...\hat{\beta}_pX_p$

where $X_i$ are the independent variables and $\hat{\beta}$ are the estimated parameters.